# SQL server Sorting column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, database-administration

if suppose we have written a SQL select command without using order by clause then what will be the column on which the sorting will done while displaying records of select command...

```
create table test
(
ID int identity (1,1) primary key,
em_id int,
name varchar(20),
address varchar(20)
mobile number int
)
```

suppose the table is like above structure and select command like

```
select * from test
```

then how can i check the column name on which the sorting is done by sql..

Comment: In SQL, the language, if you want a specific ordering add an `ORDER BY` clause. There's no other way to specify ordering. Even when a specific *storage* order will return data in whatever way is cheapest unless an `ORDER BY` clause is specified. That's quite common eg when parallel processing is used

Comment: Well, not possible to enforce some default column sorting at the creation of the table.  But in Sql Server 2012 I assume you could create a view with an `ORDER BY` if you combine it with a `OFFSET 0 ROWS` or a `TOP`. But unsure if that would work in SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 3):

In a query like this:

```
select *
from test;
```

**The result set is not sorted.**

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Running the query multiple times can result in the same result set -- but with the rows in a different order.

If you want a specific ordering in the result set, you need to include an `order by`.

You may be confusing "ordering" with the clustered index.  If so, you can find the keys in a clustered index (if one exists) using the system metadata tables.  But the data is not guaranteed to be returned by the clustered index *unless you have an `order by`* in the query.

Comment: so how the date will be fetch from the data file? data will be fatch on as per the insert order?

Comment: @SarveshBandekar No, as Gordon told you: There is no implicit sort order. The same call can return differently sorted sets. If you need a sort order, you **must** use an `ORDER BY` on the outermost query.

Comment: okkk thanks i got it.... sorry for this silly question but if suppose i have written a order by clause but then also i want to check the order by column in statistics only then how can i check the column same....

Answer (score 0):

If you want a specific ordering in the result set, you need to include an order by clause.
By default order by(if you specify order by clause) is in ASC order.